Division over a discrete function
I have a problem where i need to find the groundstate of a system with imaginary time propagation. My one dimensional problem looks like this
$$\dot{\Psi}=\left (-\Delta + |\Psi|^2+\frac{\nabla}{\Psi^*}\right)\Psi\,\, .$$
I want to do propagate an initial state (given as a discrete array) in imaginary time. I only want to propagate in the real space. It is easy to write the Laplace operator as a matrix. The part $|\Psi|^2$ is diaogonal in real space, but how to deal with the last term? I can write the gradient as a matrix. But how to divide over the array $\Psi^*$?
By the way. I split the time evolution operator up. So i propagate every term of the RHS on its own.
Thanks for help
